# GSuite API: authorised apps and their users

Tags: google-workspace

I'm trying to get a list of :

- all third-party applications that have been authorised by my colleagues
- which colleague has authorised which application
- what scopes that application has (read emails, add events, ..)

I can use the CustomerUsageReports API to get a list of authorised applications and the amount of employees using them:

```
72 => {#110
+"client_id": "<censoredjustincase>.apps.googleusercontent.com"
+"client_name": "Slack"
+"num_users": "15"
}
```

But this doesn't give me an idea on who uses it and with which scopes.

I can also get a list of all authorization events in the last x days:

```
    {#41
  +"kind": "admin#reports#activity"
  +"actor": {#26
    +"email": "<censored>"
    +"profileId": "<censored>"
  }
  +"events": array:1 [
    0 => {#25
      +"name": "authorize"
      +"parameters": array:3 [
        0 => {#23
          +"name": "client_id"
          +"value": "<censored>.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        }
        1 => {#24
          +"name": "app_name"
          +"value": "ProsperWorks CRM"
        }
        2 => {#37
          +"name": "scope"
          +"multiValue": array:2 [
            0 => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
            1 => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, this list of events is limited to the last 180 days. Whatever applications were authorised before that time might not show up again, I presume.

Does anyone know how to get a full list of authorised third-party applications, with their scope and users?